# Accessing authenticated servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, basic-authentication

I'm trying to access a site/servlet with a required authentication, which pops-up a window and ask for username and password. However when I try to access it through my "proxy servlet" I can't get the pop-up working although the client side gets this kind of HTTP response:

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  2429
Content-Type    text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date    Mon, 02 Apr 2012 09:52:44 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 07:30:00 SGT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=039823E2FAB18C59C9B351F2C6B1909E; Path=/manager/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="Tomcat Manager Application"
```

Isn't it when client (browser) gets response like this with `WWW-Authenticate` it will show a popup?

Comment: Paste mapping code for both case

Comment: You mean the servlet mapping?

Comment: yes.. servlet mapping. The problem is related with Servlet filters

Comment: I see, I actually have a filter for my proxy servlet. From what you say the problem is there.

Comment: BTW, I just turned off the filter from the web.xml, still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

Browser should receive [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) `401` (as in this [basic authentication example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example)) to present the pop-up window to the user. It won't work with `200` or any other status code in spite of `WWW-Authenticate` header.